# XML Deserialization with multiple elements with same name but different content

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

Please help me to build model for deserialization of XML with multiple tags with same name but different content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<found>
<prefixes>
    <prefix name="Name1">Val1</prefix>
    <prefix name="Name2">Val2</prefix>
</prefixes>
<objects>
    <object handle="0">
        <User>
            <familyName>Family</familyName>
            <givenName>Given1</givenName>
        </User>
    </object>
    <object handle="0">
        <User>
            <familyName>Family2</familyName>
            <givenName>Given2</givenName>
        </User>
    </object>
</objects>
<objects>
    <object handle="0">
        <User>
            <familyName>Family3</familyName>
            <givenName>Given3</givenName>
        </User>
    </object>
    <object handle="0">
        <User>
            <familyName>Family4</familyName>
            <givenName>Given4</givenName>
        </User>
    </object>
</objects>
```

This XML contains 2 collection wrapped in tag `<objects>`. For debug purposes I used the same content for both `<objects>` tags, but in reality they'll be different. Furthermore content of each of these collection could change, but the structure of document is the same: it contains collection of prefixes, and 2 collections of objects.

Here are data objects used to serialize/deserialize this xml:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "found", IsNullable = true)]
public class UserProfileDto
{
    [XmlArray("prefixes", Order = 0)]
    [XmlArrayItem("prefix", IsNullable = false)]
    public PrefixDto [] Prefixes { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("objects", Order = 1)]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "object", Type = typeof(ObjectDto), IsNullable = false)]
    public ObjectDto[] Objects { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("objects", Order = 2)]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "object", Type = typeof(ObjectDto), IsNullable = false)]
    public ObjectDto[] AnotherObjects { get; set; }
}

public class PrefixDto
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectDto
{
    [XmlElement("User")]
    public UserDto User { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class UserDto
{
    [XmlElement("familyName")]
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("givenName")]
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is - that serialization works fine with this model class, however when deserializing, property `AnotherObjects` is always null. Another strange thing - is that property `Objects` (in class `UserProfileDto`) is filled with data from the last element `<object>`.

Please help to deal with this deserialization.

Comment: If you have elements with the same name, but different objects behind them, you could use your own serialization/deseralizaton methods. Using XElement could help you.

Comment: The xml you submitted has the same content. So your question does not make sense. Show xml with different content, then we'll talk.

Comment: Alexander, xml is corrects. I need to deserialize exactly this xml. This xml document represents list of prefixes and 2 lists of the same objects. The challenge is that 2 tags of <objects> have different meanings e.g. first tag <objects> represents list of regular users, and second one - list of group managers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this problem.
Before serialization xslt transformation is applied to convert xml to desired format and then resulting xml deserialized into an objects.

For this example I applied following xslt transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/found">
  <found>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="prefixes"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="objects[position()=1]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="objects[position()=2]"/>
  </found>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="prefixes">
  <prefixes>
    <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
  </prefixes>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="objects[position()=1]">
  <hitObjects>
    <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
  </hitObjects>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="objects[position()=2]">
  <ancillaryObjects>
     <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
  </ancillaryObjects>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```